# Entity Framework Error: Invalid object name 'dbo.XXXXXXX'

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have the following data table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuthorizeAttrib]
    (
      [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL
    , [ControllerName] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL
    , [ActionName] [VARCHAR](100) NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_AuthorizeAttrib] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )
    )
ON  [PRIMARY];
```

In code I have the following:

```
public class StsDatabase : MembershipRebootDbContext<StsUser, StsGroup>
{
    public StsDatabase() : this("name=MembershipReboot") { }
    public StsDatabase(string name) : base(name) { this.RegisterUserAccountChildTablesForDelete<StsUser>(); }

    public DbSet<AuthorizeAttrib> AuthorizeAttribs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RuleSet> RuleSets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RuleSetRole> RuleSetRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.ConfigureMembershipRebootUserAccounts<StsUser>();
        modelBuilder.ConfigureMembershipRebootGroups<StsGroup>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AuthorizeAttribMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RuleSetMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RuleSetRoleMap());
    }
}
```

And the AuthorizeAttribMap looks like:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AuthorizeAttrib>
{
    public AuthorizeAttribMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.ControllerName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.ActionName)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("AuthorizeAttrib");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.ControllerName).HasColumnName("ControllerName");
        this.Property(t => t.ActionName).HasColumnName("ActionName");
    }
}
```

I've even tried running with *AND* without the following:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Nothing seems to be working.  When I break on the code before it executes and copy the SQL then run it in SQL Mangler it runs fine.  The SQL produced by LINQ:

```
SELECT  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
      , [Extent1].[ControllerName] AS [ControllerName]
      , [Extent1].[ActionName] AS [ActionName]
FROM    [dbo].[AuthorizeAttrib] AS [Extent1];
```

I am scratching my head as to what else would cause this challenge!

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try calling "base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);" before you set the convention. Also check the base class for potential conflicts?

Comment: This method overrides the base method.  If the base method ran, it would configure the defaults rather than all of the overrides I have built.  I've checked the base class for conflicts and there are none as these are brand new objects.

Comment: If the context is capable of generating correct SQL your EF configuration is OK. The table is either not in the database you're actually accessing (maybe another one than you *think* you access) or it's not authorized.

Comment: On which side would I check authorization?  The connection string uses SQL login so the account is stable.  I can log into the SQL Manager and run the query and get results.  I checked the table permissions on the SQL side and they *appear* correct, though I am not a SQL security expert.

Comment: Never mind.  In a way you were right.  When the build/publish script ran, the wrong web.config was pulled in.  Still pointing to the Dev DB instead of the Security Dev DB.  Note to self:  ALWAYS check the web.configs.  Too many moving parts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the build/publish script ran, the wrong web.config was pulled in. Still pointing to the Dev DB instead of the Security Dev DB. Note to self: ALWAYS check the web.configs. Too many moving parts!